# TS7017 implict any type + type inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Here's the condensed snippet that's erroring:

```
export default function formatSql(this: EscapeFunctions, sqlQuery: string, values: QueryParams) {

    if (isPlainObject(values)) {
        console.log(values[p]); // <-- Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type 'QueryParams' has no index signature.
    } else if (Array.isArray(values)) {
        // ...
    } else {
        throw new Error(`Unsupported values type`);
    }
    // ...
}
```

`QueryParams` is defined as:

```
export type QueryParams = StringMap | any[];
export interface StringMap {
    [_:string]: any,
}
```

So, `StringMap` has an "index signature" if I'm not mistaken, and `isPlainObject` is defined as:

```
export function isPlainObject(obj: any): obj is object  {
    return isObject(obj) && (
        obj.constructor === Object  // obj = {}
        || obj.constructor === undefined // obj = Object.create(null)
    );
}
```

So I'd think that the `isPlainObject` check would rule out the `any[]` type, and thus `values` should necessarily be inferred as `StringMap`, but that doesn't appear to be what's happening.

Even if I make `isPlainObject` return `obj is StringMap`, Typescript still complains.

How come? Is there any way I can make this work without typecasting everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, an Array still conforms to the type `{[key: string]: any}`. You can verify this by doing `const test: StringMap = [];`. The TypeScript compiler will not complain. So you first have to rule out the possibility that `values` is an array.

Next, your function `isPlainObject` has the return type defined as `obj is object`. That is too generic, and will cause your code block to "forget" that the object has an index signature. It needs to be `obj is StringMap`.

So in practice, you need to do two things:

1. In your first `if` statement, check if the value is an array
2. Change your `isPlainObject` return type declaration to `obj is StringMap`

Basically it will look something like this:

```
export function isPlainObject(obj: any): obj is StringMap  {
  // ...
}

export default function formatSql(values: QueryParams) {
  if (Array.isArray(values)) {
    // ...
  } else if (isPlainObject(values)) {
    console.log(values[p]);
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Unsupported values type`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to check for array first because arrays are technically objects? Is that why?